# Using 15 V laptop charger to power 14.4 V speakers

Tags: power-supply

I recently moved from the U.S. to the U.K., to find that the mains voltage is different. Sadly, my speakers do not have a regulated power supply, as they were only designed for U.S. mains. (http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/2,review-1083-7.html)

On the speaker box, where the power cable enters, it says:

> 110-120 V, ~60 Hz, 266 mA

So I pulled the speakers apart, and the power cable leads to a transformer/rectifier unit that has written on it the following:

> I/P: 120 Vac 60 HZ
>
> O/P: 14.4 Vdc 1A

The DC output is then routed to the circuit board inside the speaker.

I have the following questions:

1) Is 266 mA the current the entire unit draws? If so, why is there a transformer/rectifier that can provide 1A?

2) Can I use a 15V 2A laptop charger (possibly with a 0.6V diode on it to drop the voltage) to power the circuit board? Or would the charging circuit be a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1) The power into the unit is Power = Voltage x Current: 120V x 0.266A = 32W ca.

Power out of the voltage converter part (max) is 14.4V x 1A = 14.4W
So it is actually giving out less power than is put into it. There are conversion losses and safety design considerations that limits the output power.

2) Yes. It will probably work. Probably without the diode also, but we don't know without more information about the circuit being supplied by the power source.

The "charging circuit" you are referring to probably doesn't exist in the laptop charger. A laptop charger is most of the time just a power source. The charging regulation is usually done in the computer or in some occasions on a PCB inside the battery.

Comment: The "charging circuit" does exist, however, it's part of the laptop, not the external power supply.

Comment: Yes, I'm rephrasing that. The intention was that the "voltage and current regulation" part is the charging circuit.

Comment: 15V 5A power supply connected directly to the circuit works! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Mark the answer if you like! :)